# Redirect on Google after Successfully Submit Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I created a form with name, email, phone fields.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 my">
 <form  role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contact_name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" required="true" type="text"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email_from">Email address</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="email_from" name="email_from" type="email"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone No</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="pnone" name="phone" type="text"/>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary center-block" style="width: 35%;" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div
```

I want action and onsubmit event.
Action is for where to submit my form and onsubmit for redirect after successfully submited.
And after successfully submitted I want to redirect to Google.

Comment: "redirect on google"? explain in detail.

Comment: update question with code, what you did so for..

Comment: Do you redirect after clik in submit, or after saving your data ?  explain in detail please

Answer (score 0):

```
   ....   
   document.formNameGoesHere.submit();
   window.location = "http://www.google.com";
});
```

Comment: You need to explain how this works and where to put it; the question is tagged for JS but the author might not know what to do with it.  Additionally, I'm not sure this will work since the `submit()` action likely redirects to another page before the location can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
        window.location="www.google.com";
    })
})
```